# Can a script be too new for a google sheet?

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I work on a google sheet that has several departments looking at and/or adding data to all day long every day. I have been working on making scripts to make my departments life a lot easier.I created an exact duplicate of the sheet so I could make sure it works before executing new scripts.

I have one that sets up an order, sends an email and puts it on the calendar all in one click. It works great.

In the email we need to send a link to a job folder. So we have a script to find that folder and get the link to it.

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("12345 - Help me")
var in = folder.next()
var link = in.getUrl()
```

In my testing grounds this works exactly how it should. When I put it into the actual sheet that we work in I get an error

> "Error    Exception: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

I have been trying to figure it out for 4 days so far and am getting nowhere.

- I had the "owner" of the sheet transfer it into my ownership incase that was the problem.
- I moved it to a shared drive.
- Made a copy of the whole spreadsheet to test it; it worked in the copy just fine.

To change over to a new spreadsheet will be a lot of work that would have to take place after work hours when no one should be using it. I am hoping there is a way to refresh the spreadsheet in such a way that we need to reapprove scripts (or something). The spreadsheet in question was created in 2018. I am wondering if its just to old for the script; not that that makes any sense but, I cant think of anything else.
Thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. On this site questions that looks for debugging help, i.e. to find why a script is not working, it's generally expected that the asker includes a [mcve]. In the specific case of Google Apps Script it's important to include project info like if it's is using the Google Cloud Platform default project or a standard project, the runtime that is being used (the old runtime or the new runtime), among other details.

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> The spreadsheet in question was created in 2018. I am wondering if its just to old for the script; not that that makes any sense but, I cant think of anything else.

Nowadays Google Apps Scripts supports two runtimes, the old (Rhino) and the new (V8). There are posts sharing that changing the runtime to the one or the other fixed an issue. Considering this, the first thing to check if what runtime are being used on each Google Apps Script that are being used as "testing grounds" and in production as sometimes one of the source of "confusions" is to use different runtime.

Another thing to try is to create a standard Google Cloud Platform Project (GCP) to replace the default GCP project. On this project enable the Google Drive API.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly Rubén! I checked; they are both running on V8. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Striker Added another thing to try.

Comment: there was already a GCP setup and I went in to add the API and it still didn't work. I ended up trying different things that led me to deleting a critical OAuth ID and I couldn't get it back. I ended up just working a 13 hour day copying it and reestablishing all the links and restrictions. I still have a long road of repairs to do for sheets that were pulling data from it but, the critical stuff is fixed. Thanks for the help! I guess we'll never be sure what was going on.